# Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2013 for XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Recently installed VS 2013 Update 2. I am developing a WPF application and the first thing I have stumbled upon was absence of intellisense. I tried reinstalling, repairing, and any other suggestions found on stackoverflow. Resetting settings, enablig show members in options for text editor did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of frustration I found out that my greed to save space on HDD was the issue - I have unchecked Blend install during setup.

**Solution:**
Install blend (you can add it as a feature to an existing instalation of VS through same setup)

And after I installed blend, XAML intellisense started working as expected. Hope this saves some time for someone.