# IntelliSense for Data Binding not working - followup

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Having got IntelliSense for Data Binding working in a simple test application, thanks to the answer to my [previously raised question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394295/intellisense-for-data-binding-not-working), I'm now trying to apply what I've learnt to the actual application I'm working on. Again I'm encountering problems that I don't understand. A snippet of my code is below - I've had to change names to protect propriety information:

```
<Page x:Class="MyProject.Views.Pages.MyPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="450"
      xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
      xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
      Title="My View"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="True" KeepAlive="True" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
    <Page.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <Converters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:MyViewModel}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I'm getting an error message on the line `<StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:MyViewModel}">`:

> The name "MyViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels".

The error doesn't make sense `MyViewModel` does exist within the `MyProject.ViewModels` namspace.
Any suggestions? I've tried a clean rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyProject.ViewModels` namepsace is within a  different assembly to the `MyProject.Views.Pages` and it appears to necessary to add `;assembly=MyProject.ViewModels` to the `xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels` delcaration:

```
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels;assembly=MyProject.ViewModels"
```

I assumed that because the assembly is referenced by the project, I wouldn't need to specify an assembly, just as I don't have to specify an assembly when using a namespace within a C# code file.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error and I got it many times before. Each time I have this error, it come from the fact that I have other errors and my code won't compile for other reasons. As soon as I fixed all other errors, my code compile and VisualStudio find all 'd:' missing references... if they really exists.

Also, as an alternative, if you instanciate your ViewModel with its default constructor, I suggest to use something like (without using 'd:'):

```
...
</Page>
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MyViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

It will solve your problem forever.

I haven't tried it yet, but perhaps that with Roslyn (the new VS2015 compiler) this problem will go away. I hope :-)